# SQL Server Contains Predicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like, containstable

I'm putting together a quick search that has several fields like category, year, etc. I'm also trying to include a field for search term that uses the contains predicate on the title column. I'd like to use the same query for if they've selected a search term or not so I tried the following, but I always get 0 results if the @SearchTerm is empty.

```
AND (
@SearchTerm IS NOT NULL AND
CONTAINS((Title), @SearchTerm)
)
```

Is there an easy way to ignore the searchterm contains section if the searchterm is empty?

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing to something like `@SearchTerm IS NULL OR CONTAINS(...)`.

Comment: Usually with contains I tend to push the values in via dynamic SQL. That way you can handle how to check multiple words, partial matches etc.  Not the most graceful approach, but does give a lot more control.  Especially if the parameter is coming from a user entered field. I can post you an example if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic you want is `OR`, not `AND`, phrased like this:

```
AND (@SearchTerm IS NULL OR CONTAINS((Title), @SearchTerm))
```

Comment: I think this will return every row when `@SearchTerm` has a value.

Comment: I think you need IS NULL here. Remove NOT.

Comment: Unfortunately that just returns the entire result set when there is a search term.

Comment: Sean Lange - Can you expand on that?